# Inputting string and intergers from a text file into variable

Tags: c++, file-io

Hey is it possible to have a text file which its contents are:

```
Weapon Name: Katana
Damage: 20
Weight: 6
```

Is it possible to assign these bits of information into member variables of a weapons class?.
So that when i call getWeaponName in my main i will get Katana?

I was looking around google and i can get the whole text file input but its not assigned to any variable.

The code i have so far is:

```
Weapons :: Weapons()
{
    this->weaponName = "";
    this->damage = 0;
    this->weight = 0;
}

Weapons :: Weapons(string weaponName,int damage,int weight)
{
    this->weaponName = weaponName;
    this->damage = damage;
    this->weight = weight;
}

void Weapons ::  getWeapon()
{
    ifstream myfile ("Weapons\\Katana.txt");
    string line;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile.good())
        {
            getline (myfile,weaponName,'\t');//This line gets the entire text file.
            //getline (myfile,damage,'\t');
            //getline (myfile,weight,'\t');
            //myfile >> weaponName;
            //myfile >> damage;
            //myfile >> weight;
            cout << weaponName<< "\n";
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is with one question after another insisting on using `this->XXX` to refer to member variables? Has some author even worse than Schildt come onto the scene recommending this stupidity or something?

Comment: I was actually recommeded this on Stack Overflow....

Comment: What is with one question after another insisting on not using initializer lists?

Comment: @stijn i have i just didnt include it in the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
getline (myfile, weaponName, '\t');
```

to

```
getline (myfile, weaponName);
```

What your version is doing is telling `getline` to grab everything in the file, up to a tab character, and I'm guessing you don't have any tab characters.  The version I'm recommending - with no delimiter specified - will get characters up to a newline.  So it should read in `Weapon Name: Katana`.

Then you still need to extract "Katana".  Assuming your input file has a very fixed format, you can simply do something like

```
weaponName = weaponName.substr(weaponName.find_first_of(':') + 2);
```

This will take the substring starting at the position 2 after the ':'.

#### Edit

Using `weaponName` is not exactly proper for your getline statement.  `weaponName` is a string, but at that point, you're just looking for a line.  You already have the proper variables in place in `getWeapon()`.  We just need to use them:

```
void Weapons ::  getWeapon()
{
    ifstream myfile ("Weapons\\Katana.txt");
    string line;
    string number;
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile.good())
        {
            getline (myfile,line);
            weaponName = line.substr(line.find_first_of(':') + 2);
            getline (myfile,line);
            number = line.substr(line.find_first_of(':') + 2);
            damage = atoi(number.c_str());
            getline (myfile,line);
            number = line.substr(line.find_first_of(':') + 2);
            weight = atoi(number.c_str()); 
            cout << weaponName<< "\n";
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
 }
```

**Note:** you'll need to `#include <stdlib.h>` for `atoi` to work.

Honestly, this still isn't very robust.  Others have offered you better solutions for looking at the input to see what the data is, and reading and storing all your data, but this should show you the very basics.

Comment: Of course, if you have sufficient control of the inputs, etc, it might be better to use a standard parseable format, such as XML or JSON, rather than hard-coding each line.  Or you could make your parsing more robust, by not caring about order of the lines - extract the part before the ':' out, and do a big switch (or if/else/else/else/else etc) block.

Comment: The find first of is this part of the string library.  Im getting an error when im using it :S

Comment: My mistake, sorry.  It should be `find_first_of`.  I'll fix the code.

Comment: So ive got the weapon name:)  any idea how to do this for integers because when im using getline on damage and weight i get an error because getline only takes in fstream,char...

Comment: Why not use weapon name.  Id like the input "Katana" to be then = to the member variable weaponName.

Comment: Because weight and damage aren't weapon names.  :-P

Comment: We are definitelt getting somewhere... I have the 3 variable weapnName, damage and weight printing out.  But weight is supposed to be 6 and at the moment the value is 20...

Comment: Time to learn some debugging!  Fire up your good ol' debugger, and look at some variables.  Or, if that's tough, use lots of `cout`.  Questions will be:  what's the value of `damage`?  Is it 6, or 20?  What's the value of `line` and `number` right before you set the weight?  It's possible either the code or the file or the cout you have has something in the wrong order, so look at the details to help you figure it out.

Comment: Thats great Scott Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

You will need to parse each line of your file. So, change the function

```
getline(myfile, weaponName, '\t');
```

to

```
getline(myfile, weaponName);
```

and parse result.

Do something like that:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  string line = "Weapon Name: Katana";

  int pos = line.find(':');
  string weaponName;
  if ( line.substr(0, pos) == "Weapon Name")
    weaponName = line.substr(pos+1, line.npos);

  printf("%s\n", weaponName.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need/want to distinguish between "weapons" (plural) and a single weapon. To make much sense, each individual weapon has the characteristics you're reading (name, weight, damage). So, weapons will be a collection of individual weapon objects, each of which has the characteristics.

Based on that, we can attempt to write some meaningful code:

```
class weapon {
    std::string name;
    int damage;
    int weight;
public:
    std::string get_name() { return name; }
```

Now, we want a `weapon` to be able to "reconstitute" itself from data stored in a file. Note, however, that right now we're writing a `weapon` class, so we're only going to deal with *one* weapon, not a whole collection of them:

```
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, weapon &w) { 
    std::ignore(is, 1024, ':'); // ignore the "Weapon Name:" header
    std::getline(is, w.name);
    std::ignore(is, 1024, ':'); // ignore the "Damage:" header
    is >> w.damage;
    std::ignore(is, 1024, ':');  // ignore the "Weight:" header
    is >> w.weight;
    return is;
}
```

Though we don't need it just yet, let's create a matching function to write out a weapon in the correct format as well:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, weapon const &w) { 
   return os << "Weapon Name: " << w.name << "\n"
             << "Damage: " << w.damage << "\n"
             << "Weight: " << w.weight << "\n";
}
```

With that, we can read the data for a single weapon. Then we need some way to store multiple weapons. Lacking a reason to do otherwise, our first choice for that is normally an `std::vector`. If we want to fill that with the data from a file, we can do it something like this:

```
// open a file of all the weapons data:
std::ifstream in("weapons.txt");

// initialize the vector from the data in the file:
std::vector<weapon> weapons((std::istream_iterator<weapon>(in)),
                             std::istream_iterator<weapon>());
```

With this in place we can (for example) list all the weapons (here we're going to use the "operator<<" we defined above):

```
 std::copy(weapons.begin(), weapons.end(), 
           std::ostream_iterator<weapon>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

If we want an abbreviated list with just the name of each weapon, we can do something like this:

```
for (auto const &w : weapons)
    std::cout << w.get_name() << "\n";
```

Comment: There is a problem with getLine and integers.  Damage and Weight are ints :(

Comment: This supposes that the attributes always occur in the same order, and that each is always present.  If you do this, you might as well go with the original code: `WEAPON("katana", "samurai sword",
 0, 0, 0,  4, 40, 80, 10, 12, 1, S,   P_LONG_SWORD, IRON, HI_METAL)`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: What original code is that? In any case, expecting the file to be in the correct format is *hardly* equivalent to hard-coding all the data, and you know it. Hard-coding the data means you need to re-compile the code to make any change to the available weapons, which isn't the case at all with the weapons in an external file. An external file also (for example) makes it easy to serialize the weapons held by a character at a given time, to allow things like saving and restoring a game.

Comment: @JerryCoffin and your explanation is exactly why im using a txt file so that i can save and restore.  I was just having a test of my code and the damage and weight seem to have the values of the defaut constructor rather than taking in anything from the file.

Comment: @JerryCoffin The original code is from the sources of Nethack.  But it could just as easily be in a configuration file.  _Not_ verifying the labels when reading a configuration file is a recipe for disaster.  Even if the rules of the format say that they have to be in a certain order, at some point, someone will edit the file, and accidentally delete a line.  At the very least, you have to be able to detect the error.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Do you believe that anything you can do to Nethack could possibly qualify as a "disaster"? IMO, you're overstating the case drastically. This isn't exactly what you'd call mission critical software here...

Comment: @JerryCoffin It's true that it's not mission critical.  And just about anything would improve the quality of the current sources.  But still... there's no point in writing out the labels if you're not going to use them.  If they're there, its so that some human can edit the file.  And screw it up.  And even for some trivial game, you do want to know if it's screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

Your format looks like a variant of a typical .ini file.  There
are lots of parsers around for that, if you can modify the
format to make it conform.  That would be by far the easiest
solution.  Otherwise: how are the various weapons separated in
the file?  Is it by an empty line, or is it because the first
entry is always `"Weapon Name"`?  In the first case, I would use
something like the following to read the file (in a free
function, not as a member):

```
std::auto_ptr<Weapon> currentWeapon;
Line line;
int lineNumber = 0;
while ( source >> line ) {
    ++ lineNumber;
    if ( line.empty() ) {
        if ( currentWeapon.get() != NULL ) {
            weaponCollection.insert( currentWeapon );
        }
        currentWeapon.release();
    } else {
        Line::const_iterator pivot 
            = std::find( line.begin(), line.end(), ':' );
        if ( pivot == line.end() ) {
            //  Output error message, using lineNumber...
        } else {
            if ( currentWeapon.get() == NULL ) {
                currentWeapon.reset( new Weapon );
            }
            std::string key( strip( std::string( line.begin(), pivot ) ) );
            std::string value( strip( std::string( pivot + 1, line.end() ) ) );
            if ( key == "WeaponName" ) {
                currentWeapon->weaponName = value;
            } else if ( key == "Damage" ) {
                currentWeapon->damage = asInt( value );
            } else if ( key == "Weight" ) {
                currentWeapon->weight = asInt( value );
            } // ...
            else {
                // output error message...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Line` is a class in my toolbox, that I use a lot for this sort
of thing.  It's basically:

```
class Line : private std::string
{
public:
    typedef std::string::iterator iterator;
    //  ...
    using std::string::empty;
    using std::string::begin;
    //  ...
};
```

The only difference between it and `std::string` is that its
`operator>>` calls `std::getline`, then "cleans up" the results,
by removing any trailing white space (including a possible
`'\r'`, because the file was written under Windows, but I'm
reading it under Unix); in this case, it might be useful to make
it also remove any leading white space.  (Mine also has
a manipulator which sets a comment character; if this is set, it
removes any text from this character to the end of the line,
before trimming trailing whitespace.
(From experience: do provide some sort of facility for commenting
in the file.  You'll regret it if you don't.)

And `asInt` is, of course:

```
int
asInt( std::string const& original )
{
    std::istringstream s( original );
    int results;
    s >> results >> std::ws;
    if ( !s || s.get() != EOF ) {
        //  Error...
    }
    return results;
}
```

Again, something that you should have in your toolbox already.

If the key to a new weapon is the `"Weapon Name"` attribute,
skip the empty line business (or treat empty lines as comments),
and store any existing Weapon and create the new one in the
handling for `"Weapon Name"`.

If you throw on error, above, you'll need to use a try...catch
block to output the error and continue.  You might also want to
mark that there was an error somewhere, and abort the game if
so.